# How to wrap text with in a column while writing in csv file using python

Tags: python, django, export-to-csv

I am trying to export a file as csv. I need to wrap text for a particular column while writing in csv file. I have a too long string. i need to write it in a csv file using python. While trying to write, it doesn't write in a single cell. some of the lines are written into next rows. I need to write the whole string in a single cell. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is not formatted. If you want to format the text in the cells, you should consider writing a proper Excel or PDF file.

Anyway it looks like that newline characters (\n or \r\n) can be used in CSV files if using semicolon as separator, so this may not be portable.

To write an Excel file, you can use libraries like `openpyxl` or `xlwt`.

Comment: ya am telling about the excel only. am writing the content using csv.writer. how could be wrap text of particular column

Comment: But are you exporting as CSV text file, or as Excel format file (XLS or XLSX) ?

Comment: am exporting as csv text file

Comment: Could you show the code you've tried thus far?
CSV's like excel do wrap long lines in a single cell and don't let them flow over to another column.
Your ',' separator would seem to the problem that's messing up.